# Using PHP to write a CSV file with Spanish characters

Tags: php, csv, utf-8

I have a php script with utf-8 encoding. In it I have an array with special characters (like and n with a ~ on top). It looks just fine in my editor. The php matches the array with text coming in from a html form and writes a csv file. When I write the file I do it like this;

```
fwrite($fp,utf8_encode($data),strlen($data)+100);
```

When I open the file it says it is utf-8 encoded but the charters are all messed up.

Comment: Is $data utf-8 already? You'd be double-encoding if so. As well, strlen is not unicode aware, and will return bad values. You should use mb_strlen() instead.

Comment: What is the `strlen($data)+100` for? If you are writing the whole string you don't need to specify a length, and the +100 doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

have you tried without using utf_encode() on the data?
it seems that you are reencoding something that's already utf-8 encoded